# Vue.js - hide a text on a page passed from App.vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am really new to Vue. I have multiple pages such as `App.vue`, `Waiting.vue`, `Reference.vue`, Switch.vue and so on. The text defined on `**App.vue**` is passed along to other pages correctly. But now I dont want to display `WELCOME` text passed from `App.vue` to `Waiting.vue` page. Is there a way that I can hide `WELCOME` from `Waiting.Vue` page only?

**App.vue**

```
<div id="app">
 <b-container>
  <b-col lg="5">
    WELCOME
  </b-col>
 </b-container>
</div>
```

**Waiting.vue**

```
<div id="app">
 <p class="teamTitle">TEAMS ON DECK</p>
</div>
```

**Ouput for Waiting.vue**

```
WELCOME
TEAMS ON DECK
```

Comment: what do you mean by passed text?

Comment: Currently I am using App.vue content to pass on other pages. I have like more than 10 pages of vue which use the content passed from App.vue. But for only one page I dont want to use the content passed along or hide it. Is there a way that I can hide a content passed to that certain page only ?

Comment: is it passed via props?

Comment: Content is just defined on the App.vue and it displays the text to other pages. For example, if div id="app" of App.vue , contains <p>WELCOME</p>. Then that WELCOME text will be displayed at the top for other pages as well.

Comment: are you using vue router?

Comment: Yes. const router = new VueRouter({
 routes
});

new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 router,
 render: h => h(App)
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let suppose that the `Waiting`  page path is `/waiting` so you should do :

```
<div id="app">
 <b-container>
  <b-col lg="5" v-if="$route.path!=='/waiting'">
    WELCOME
  </b-col>
 </b-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that App.vue is acting as parent component and has content that is visible in the page. That being the case, there are multiple ways of hiding information.

1. If you use a router and `Waiting.vue` is on a distinct route you can check for route params to selectively hide text. For e.g. in `App.vue`.

   ```
   <b-col lg="5" v-if="!this.$route.fullPath === '/waiting'">
    WELCOME
   </b-col>
   ```
2. If you use global storage like Vuex, just set a variable within Vuex when `Waiting.vue` is loaded and set the variable to something else in other components
3. If you are having everything on a single page for any reason, pass a variable as prop and selectively hide the element (similar to [1])

   App.vue

   ```
   <Waiting :hide="true"/>
   ```

   Waiting.vue

   ```
   <b-col lg="5" v-if="!hide">
     WELCOME
   </b-col>

   <!-- other code --> 
   <script>
     export default {
       props: {
         default: false,
         type: Boolean,
         required: false
       }
     }
   </script>
   ```